# Update multiple records in multiple properties in Generic Repository

Tags: c#, generics, entity-framework-core, repository-pattern, .net-5

I created a repository project will help me in my other projects.
I want to add a new `method` that will update multiple records in multiple properties and I have no idea to do that.

**Work environment:**

```
Entity framework core

.Net 5
```

**What I tried:**
I already created a `method` will update many records **but just in one property** as shown below

```
public void UpdateMany<TEntity>(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filterExpression, Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> updateThe, object value) where TEntity : class
{
    // Get the records to be updated depending on the filter expression
    var recordsToBeUpdated = Context.Set<TEntity>().Where(filterExpression).ToList();

    // Update the selected records
    recordsToBeUpdated.ForEach(entity =>
                               { 
                                   entity.GetType().GetProperty(updateThe.GetPropertyAccess().Name)?.SetValue(entity, value);
                               });

}
```

**So please how can I update multiple records in multiple properties using an expression or any other solution?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not to use Action directly? like this

```
 public static void UpdateMany<TEntity>(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filterExpression, Action<TEntity> setProperty) where TEntity : class
 {
     // Get the records to be updated depending on the filter expression
     var recordsToBeUpdated = Context.Set<TEntity>().Where(filterExpression).ToList();

     // Update the selected records
     recordsToBeUpdated.ForEach(setProperty);
 }
```

and like this to use

```
UpdateMany<Entity>(e => e.Foo == "Bar", e => e.SomeProperty = someValue);
```

or

```
UpdateMany<Entity>(e => e.Foo == "Bar", e => 
{
    e.SomeProperty = someValue;
    e.SomeOtherProperty = xyz;
    ...
});
```

Comment: I like this answer but I have a question is that solution works with updating multiple properties, should I use `UpdateMany<Entity>(e => e.Foo == "Bar", e => e.SomeProperty = someValue,e=>e.otherProperty);` or what ?? and massive thanks

Comment: You can do with object what ever you want. Like this
e => {
    e.Property1 = propValue1;
    e.Property2 = a + b;
...
}

Answer (score 1):

If you can use [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) you can populate the entries to update with the value as JSON.

```
public void UpdateMany<TEntity>(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filterExpression, object value) where TEntity : class
{
    // Get the records to be updated depending on the filter expression
    var recordsToBeUpdated = Context.Set<TEntity>().Where(filterExpression).ToList();

    // Create the patch JSON
    var patch = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);

    // Update the selected records
    recordsToBeUpdated.ForEach(entity =>
    {
        JsonConvert.PopulateObject(patch, entity);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

depending on your code structure. You can create a simple `class`, `struct`, or `record` that maps the property name and the corresponding value you want to set.

```
class PropertyMap {
    public string PropertyName {get;set;}
    public object PropertyValue {get;set;}
}
```

Then you can create a list of the properties you want to change and their corresponding values

```
var map = new List<PropertyMap>{
    new PropertyMap {
       PropertyName = nameof(Your_Property1),
       PropertyValue = "Jon Snow"
    },
    new PropertyMap {
       PropertyName = nameof(Your_Property2),
       PropertyValue = 26
    }
}
```

Then simply overload your current method to take in this map.

```
public void UpdateMany<TEntity>(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filterExpression, List<PropertyMap> maps) where TEntity : class
{
    // Get the records to be updated depending on the filter expression
    var recordsToBeUpdated = Context.Set<TEntity>().Where(filterExpression).ToList();
    var value = recordsToBeUpdated.FirstOrDefault();
   if(value != null){
     var properties = value.GetType().GetProperties();
     foreach (var entity in recordsToBeUpdated){
       foreach(map in maps){
           properties.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Name == map.PropertyName)?
                     .SetValue(entity, map.PropertyValue);
       }
     }
   }
}
```